# How can I find which records of `Data Warehouse` must be updated according to CDC captured changes?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, data-warehouse

I use `SQL Server 2012` for `OLTP` Database and created a Data Warehouse in `SQL Server 2012`.

I design `Facts` and `Dimensions` inside `Data Warehouse` with several Views.

Some of my Fact table are made by joinning several tables inside my view.

I use `CDC` (Change Data Capture) to get noticed of any `OLTP` changes and save these changes in a `Stage Database` and finally I have to update Data Warehouse based on above saved changes.

The question is how can I detect which records of my Data Warehouse have to be updated according to these saved changes by the CDC?

For more description :

I have `SalesFact` in my `Data Warehouse` that has one `View` like this

```
Select 
 Sum(T1.X),
 Sum(T2.Y),
 Sum(T3.Z),
 Sum(T4.W)
From T1
  Left join T2 On (....)
  Left join T3 On (....)
  Left join T4 On (....)
Group By T1.X,T2.Y,T3.Z,T4.W
```

Also I have 4 `CDC Tables` to save  the OLTP changes as :

```
Create Table T1Change()

Create Table T2Change()

Create Table T3Change()

Create Table T4Change()
```

so, How can I find which records of `Data Warehouse` must be updated according to these changes ?

Comment: Possibly this is just incorrect grammar, but how do you define "most change"? Greatest number of records across T1-4?

Comment: @MikeHoney : I changed my grammar.

Comment: Now I can't follow what you mean by the SalesFact View.  Why do you have Sum and Group By in the same Select?  Where's the Fact Key?

Comment: Fact Table have not Pk. but we can consider that this combination of FK are FK in my fact (1.X,T2.Y,T3.Z,T4.W). but this not make any different in my problem. how can i found which record must change(update/delete or insert) when one or more records in one or more tables in OLTP chenged?

Comment: I'm suggesting that your lack of a durable key in your design makes an update impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now understand from your further comments that your key is made of the very columns that change, and you have no durable key. I cant see how a "change" can be determined in this scenario.

I would abandon the entire CDC design, and truncate and fully refresh the destination table each time.

Comment: Are you can give me a link for best practise for design DataEarehouse and process of update it.?

Comment: I presume you mean Data Warehouse? The best source IMO is the Kimball Group - outstanding books, training, articles and forum. http://www.kimballgroup.com